# Google SMTP less secure applications

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to send email via Google SMTP server using the following simple python and mailclient.

I am a bit confused about the part where Google flags this script as insecure and requires me to allow less secure applications to access the sender's gmail account.

Is there any way to solve this problem without having to allow less secure applications to access my gmail account.

```
#Make necessary imports

import mailclient

#Craft the message
msg = mailclient.Message("This will be the subject", "This will be the body content", 'sender@gmail.com', 'recipient@domain.com')

#Create server object with gmail

s = mailclient.Server('smtp.gmail.com', '587', 'sender@gmail.com', 'senderpassword', True)

#Send email

s.send(msg)
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with code. you need to enable it in google account. refer - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: I reckon it's possible to use other mail clients without enabling less secure applications on the account. What should I include in my code to not get flagged?

Comment: Nothing can be done for Google at the code level. Try using outlook or business smtp server credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say, because Google is not very explicit for what they call *unsecure applications*, but I guess that they are applications that use ports 25 or 587. On those ports, the connection is initially established on an unencrypted channel, and becomes encrypted only when (and if) the `STARTTLS` command is issued.

So I guess that you should try to establish a connection directly over SSL on port 465. I do not know whether it is possible using `mailclient` but with the standard library modules, it should be as simple as:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "This will be the subject"
msg['From'] = 'sender@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = [ 'recipient@domain.com' ]
msg.set_content("This will be the body content")

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
server.login('sender@gmail.com', 'senderpassword')
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```